# Commerce PayPal commerce_payment_transaction PDOException[23000]

Tags: commerce, payment-gateways

I'm using commerce paypal to accept payment on a drupal website. i have configured the module as described in drupal commerce support website and created sandbox accounts both for buyer and seller. i created a test order and paid with paypal, the IPN is received successfully and it is verified according to report/dblogs with message:

> IPN validated for Order 2 with ID 7DW624906V374562U.

But after this db log there's another one which is an error with message:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062
>   Duplicate entry '' for key 'name': INSERT INTO {users} (uid, created,
>   data) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_2); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 13054
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => 1396116964 [:db_insert_placeholder_2] =>
>   a:1:{s:7:"contact";i:1;} ) in drupal_write_record() (line 7194 of
>   /home/findaper/public_html/includes/common.inc).

and type:

> commerce_payment_transaction

So, the payment is validated, but there's this error, and the event "when order first paid in full" is not firing. i have no idea how to fix this. can anyone help me with this??

drupal and all modules are the latest version. [drupal7]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Duplicate entry '' for key 'name': INSERT INTO {users} (uid, created, data)
```

This is incorrect code, since no `name` value defined for inserting, so user name is empty and name should be unique - you cann't insert second user with empty name.

Try find this code `INSERT INTO {users} (uid, created, data)` on your drupal files (modules), if no success, investigate your Rules for custom code.

Comment: Yup, the problem was a custom rule to change a field value for cart owner... thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue.
I have a custom rule that add a role to a user after he has completed his payment.
I used **site:current-user** instead of **commerce-order:owner**.
site:current-user is not defined because PayPal is an anonymous user when the IPN is processed.

So you should use **commerce-order:owner** in your custom rules when accessing user.

Hope that can help someone ;-)